# Is "The Venue in the map" or "...on the map"?

Tags: expressions

How can it be determined, if the correct version is "The Venue is in the map" or "The Venue is on the map"? And which is correct?

Comment: Correct usage can be determined by referring to a dictionary.
dictionary.com shows meanings for "off the map" and "put on the map", but nothing for "in the map".

Comment: In spite of the previous comment, there are a lot of examples of 'in the map' on the internet. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+map%2Con+the+map&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20map%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20map%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that it is a far from rare usage, but that 'on the map' is more idiomatic.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please add some context?

Comment: Normally it would be "on the map", but more context is needed to see if this might be an exception.

Comment: The venue is in the map of entertainment sites in Boston.  The venue is on the map of Boston.  **CONTEXT IS NEEDED!!!**

Answer (score 3):

**In the map** makes sense if you're talking about a map application on a smart phone.  Since this will soon be the way that most people use maps in practice, it will likely become the dominant form.

For the moment, though, **on the map** is more general, and it also carries the connotation that the Venue is worth mapping, i.e. it will appear on a screen in the app, but also on other wayfinding displays that the user might encounter on their way to its location.

So I'd say that the correct answer depends on the nature of your audience,  the importance of your venue, and the impression you are trying to convey.

Comment: Upvoted. Language is already adapting in the way you describe.

Comment: I haven't heard "in the map" used to refer to a map app. Is that something you hear frequently or have documented?

Comment: It's everyday usage, e.g. Q: "Where's the restaurant?"  A:"We can find it in the map.".  I used to hear people refer to *Google Maps*, but this is evolving.

Comment: I second "in the map" as referring to inclusion within a map, whereas "on the map" is idiomatic to whether it's noteworthy and worth marking onto a map. If it's "on the map" it's important, but whether a place is important to be "in a map" is a different question...

Answer (score 2):

A map is a 2-d representation of a 3-d space, in, would refer to "inside" whereas on represents "on-top of", and as there is no inside of a 2-d thing, the correct wording is "on the map"